# error while creating objects in python

Tags: python-object

```
class polynomial:
    def __init__(self, *coeff):
            self.coeff = coeff
    def __repr__(self):
            return 'polynomial(*{!r})'.format(self.coeff)
    def __add__(self, other):
            return polynomial(*(x + y for x, y in zip(self.coeff, other.coeff))                                                             
g = polynomial(1, 2, 3)
d = polynomial(3, 3, 4)
```

I'm trying to learn python and now I am trying to get the hang of classes and I have this Error raised
g = polynomial(1, 2, 3)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this, works perfect, after adding a closing bracket in the `__add__` function.

I can reproduce you error in a single jupyter notebook cell. However, if you separate the class definition from the instantiation in two different cells, you'd have obtained

```
return polynomial(*(x + y for x, y in zip(self.coeff, other.coeff))
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

By the way, here a [minimal complete and verificable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is usually required. If you would have tried to construct one, you typically would have included only the `__init__` function. Iterating a bit you might have come to the error in the `__add__` function. So performing such a procedure in the future, will improve your understanding an increase the chance of getting a good answer

Comment: if you're happy with an answer, feel free to accept and/or upvote it.